# Codeigniter How to load view file from subfolder with multiple files

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im new to the codeigniter and cant understand why view is not loaded from the subfolders

i write simple controller and view file

Controller location application\controllers\Test.php

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller{

 public function index()
  {
   $data = array(
      'name'  => 'ivan'
    );

  $this->load->view('test/new', $this->data);
 }
}
```

View location application\views\test\new.php

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

When i try to access url http://localhost/test/new im getting error

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

Comment: For your browsing url 'http://localhost/test/new', you need to add a function as new name in test class. test is your controller and new is your function.

You can browse  http://localhost/test , this url.

Comment: @Tushar in a folder i have index.php , new.php , history.php and ...

Comment: you change your routes directory are not? in config directory

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'Test'; in config->routes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are in index function so just create another function named new if you want to run localhost/test/new

Answer (score 0):

please run this url "http://localhost/test/", because your controller file index method are using.

Comment: in a folder i have index.php , new.php , history.php and  ...

Comment: Ok, if you want "http://localhost/test/new " this go to application/config/routes.php
and create a route `$route['test/new'] = 'test';`
or 
Create another function,  `public function new(){ $data = array(
      'name'  => 'ivan'
    ); 
 $this->load->view('test/new', $this->data);  }`
hit this url "http://localhost/test/new".